# MITM: Is and How is it possible to manipulate HTTP POST data sent by the host to the server

Tags: network, man-in-the-middle

Is it and how is it possible to modify a HTTP POST parameter that is being sent by the host to a server assuming that you are in a man-in-the-middle position in a network?

HOST(POST=foobar) --------> ATTACKER(modification) --------> SERVER(POST=barfoo)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out that mitmproxy can intercept and modify packets on the fly. It also has an API that can be implemented into python scripts. https://github.com/mitmproxy/mitmproxy

here is it's man page: 
http://manpages.org/mitmproxy

Answer (score 4):

Assuming there's no end-to-end security - such as TLS (the secure protocol that replaced SSL and underlies modern HTTPS) - then of course it's possible to modify the traffic. An HTTP POST request, like any other TCP message, is just a stream of bits traversing the various hosts that make up the [inter]net[work]. Each host receives the bits, checks where to send it to next, and retransmits it. If one of those hosts wants to, it can change the message before retransmitting it, or simply not send it along at all, or send it to the wrong destination, or...

Internet Protocol (IP), Transmission Control Protocol (TCP), and HyperText Transfer Protocol (HTTP) have no inherent security. They do not encrypt traffic, do not authenticate either the recipient or the sender, and do not protect the integrity of the message. There are security layers that can be used to provide some or all such protections, such as IPSec (typically used on enterprise local networks or for VPNs) or TLS (typically used for securing traffic over the Internet, and sometimes also within a local network; HTTPS is just HTTP over TLS). However, if such secure protocols are not used, are used incorrectly / with weak configuration, or are terminated before the message reaches its final destination (by a VPN server, or a reverse proxy or load balancer, for example), then an attacker can potentially tamper with the message en route.

Also, note that even when a secure protocol is in use, there's no way to stop an attacker with a MitM position from blocking the traffic. The attacker won't know what it says and won't be able to change the messages, but they can still simply choose to not forward along any particular stream of bits to the next host. The attacker can still tell where the message is from and where it's going (this needs to be in plain text so it can be routed correctly), and can tell its approximate size (for some protocols, can tell its exact size); these pieces of information may be sufficient for the attacker to know at least some of what's being sent. Also, an attacker may be able to convince the client to send attacker-chosen messages to the server. However, without some breach in either the server authentication or the message integrity check, the attacker still cannot modify a secure message itself.

EDIT: If you're looking for software recommendations, that's not really in scope for this site. However, any transparent HTTP proxy (a type of web server that is set up to forward messages to another server) can be used for this. Burp Suite can be configured this way if you want a hands-on view of the intercepted traffic, or an automatic one can easily be written in most programming languages (for example, the well-known HTTP MitM tool [sslstrip](https://github.com/moxie0/sslstrip) is written in python using the python-twisted-web library).

Comment: Good read, but HOW does an attacker perform this kind of manipulation/modification inside a network? Assuming you are already in a MITM position w/ ettercap or any mitm frameworks. What other tools are to use and steps to perform to modify HTTP POST parameters before reaching the server.

Comment: In your diagram, imagine that ATTACKER(modification) is a server.  It receives the HTTP Post (foobar) from HOST.  Then, it modifies it (to barfoo), and posts barfoo to SERVER.  This can be done using Node.js, python, or just about any scripting language.

Comment: Inside a local network, an attacker could poison the ARP tables of the sender and the receiver so the sender thinks its sending the traffic to the legit destination and the receiver believes its receiving the altered message it from the alleged sender.

Answer (score 0):

There are many open source proxy tools that could use to intercept HTTP traffic between client machine and Server modify it and then send it to server, here are some of these:

1. [Burp Suite Proxy](https://securityg33k.blogspot.com/2013/07/data-manipulation-intercepting-http.html)
2. [zaproxy](https://tools.kali.org/web-applications/zaproxy)